# SSL Decode Error 50 : Alert 21

Tags: openssl, tls

I have been getting an SSL decode error while connecting to the server. This is in a lab environment and I am using openssl s_client utility. It throws an decode error as 50 and alert no as 21.
On the other hand, I am using the same server configuration and trying to connect a device(client) to the same server by sending logs over tls. In this case the connection is successful. While comparing the wireshark captures, I can see one difference and its about server key exchange message. In case 1 where I am getting the error, server key exchange is taking place but in the second case where connection is successful there is no server key exchange taking place. Can this be an issue with case 1 ?

[connection failed openssl_s_client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjzXu.png)

[connection success with a device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyrGR.png)

Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: Could you show the full output from using `openssl s_client -connect <addr>:<port> -debug -msg`?  Not necessarily the address/port, of course, but the details of the handshake could be helpful.